# Name of a number that matches place in a list?

Tags: terminology

I'm pretty sure there is a term for a number that has a value that matches its place in a list but my googling is failing me. For example in 4 2 2 4 1 0 the second 4 would have a special name.

Comment: If you were to consider the sequence (list) as a function from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to the set of possible entries in the list, then an entry in the list whose entry equals the location, you have $f(i)=i$.  In this context it can be called a "fixed point," but if you weren't to make the analogy to functions in the first place, it could be confusing.

Comment: "The second $4$ in the list".